# symfony2のスタイルシートが反映されない

Tags: php, symfony2, twig

質問があります。
スタイルシートを反映するために
以下の階層にスタイルシートを置き、ソースを設定しました。
どこに問題があるでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

layout.html.twig

symfony_demo/app/Resources/assets/css/style.css←どちら？
             web/css/style.css　　　　　　　　　←？

Answer (score 1):

ローカルのWindows10＋Symfony2で試しました。

web/css/style.cssに配置して、layout.html.twigファイルに、
＜link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" /＞
を記述することで、スタイルシートが適用されるはずです。

参考サイト
http://docs.symfony.gr.jp/symfony2/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html